# Resource not found error in MVC when posting using beginform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

The below code is not working properly as expected.

The controller have an action method

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoginResult()
        {
            string name = Request.Form["name"];             
            return View("Dashboard");
        }
     public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        string strName = Request["username"].ToString();
        return View();
    }
```

and in view i have a form

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginResult", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post))
    {  
     @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.username)
    <button type="button" id="ajax_method">submit Via AJAX</button>

    }
```

and im submitting this using a function

```
<script>       
    $(function () {
        $('#ajax_method').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Dashboard/LoginResult",                             //Your Action name in the DropDownListConstroller.cs
                data: "{'AJAXParameter1':'" + $('#username').val() + "'}",  //Parameter in this function, Is case sensitive and also type must be string
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"

            }).done(function (data) {
                //Successfully pass to server and get response
                if (data.result = "OK") {
                    alert("submit successfully.");
                }
            }).fail(function (response) {
                if (response.status != 0) {
                    alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

but im getting 404 error  while clicking the button.

Even I tried adding that routerspecifications in route config.

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            name: "login",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "LoginResult", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and modified the cshtml again. But this is also not working.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("login", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post))
    {  
     @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.username)
    <button type="button" id="ajax_method">submit Via AJAX</button>

    }
```

It may be a silly error but it spoil my day. Can anyone extend a hand to solve this issue.

Comment: You url is incorrect (your method is `LoginResult()` not `Ajax()`). And then it would still fail because you not passing a value for `name` (just `AJAXParameter1`)

Comment: Change it to `url: "/Dashboard/LoginResult",` - leading slash (or better `url: @Url.Action("LoginResult", "Dashboard")',`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have corrected the url issue. But still its redirecting to another action method dashboard. confusing..

Comment: Is the `LoginResult()` method in `DashboardController`? And why do you have a method named `Dashboard` in `DashboardController`? (and did you add the leading `/`?)

Comment: Yes. LoginResult method in DashboardController. Dashboard will invoke on page load.

Comment: What is the actual error message telling you? - which url is it trying to redirect to?

Comment: Its redirecting to Dashboard instead of Loginresult.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139217/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tom-cruise).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, deleting default routing caused me issue.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

adding this resolved the issue for me. as mine is hybrid project of webforms and mvc. i didn't notice it.

Answer (score -1):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action Name", "Controller Name", FormMethod.Post))
```

I think you have to change the "Dashboard" to your controller name